# Defects probability

Tags: probability

Manufactured articles are packed in boxes, each containing 200 articles, and on average, 1.5% of all articles manufactured are defective. A box which contains 4 or more defective articles is substandard. A lorry load consists of 16 boxes, randomly chosen. Find the probability that a lorry load will include at most 2 boxes which are substandard, giving three decimal places in your answer.

My answer:

X - B(16, 0.015)

P(X ≤ 2) = binomcdf (16, 0.015, 2) = 0.998

correct answer:0.043

May I know what have I done wrong?

Comment: Hint: first compute the probability that a box is substandard, for the definition given of substandard, and percentage of defects, under the assumption that defects are independent. Then compute the probability that in a lorry load there's at most two substandard boxes, again under the assumption that defects are independent.

Comment: Hint: The probability that a box is substandard is $1-P(X\leq 3)$, where $X\sim Bin(200,0.015)$. You can apply  the CLT.

Comment: The probability that a box is substandard is about $p=0.3528$ The probability that at most 2 boxes (out of 16) are substandard is $P(Y\leq 2)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^2 \binom{16}{k}\cdot 0.3528^k\cdot (1-0.3528)^{16-k}\approx 0.043$

Answer (score 1):

Others have given good hints about how to solve the problem in the comments, but since you asked what you did wrong, let me focus on that.

There are *two* relevant probabilities here; the probability that an *article* is defective (that's $0.015$), and the probability that a *box* is substandard (that probability is *not* $0.015$). The basic mistake you have made is conflating the two.

In order to arrive at the correct solution, first find the probability that one box is defective. Then, once you have that, use that in place of $0.015$ in your computation above.